# How does awk compare a number ("40") and a string containing digits and other characters ("203-344-1234")?

Tags: awk

I have a text file `employees`:

```
Chen Cho 5/19/63 203-344-1234 $76
Tom Billy 4/12/45 913-972-4536 $102
Larry White 11/2/54 908-657-2389 $54
Bill Clinton 1/14/60 654-576-4114 $201
Steve Ann 9/15/71 202-545-8899 $58
```

When I do `awk '$4 < 40' employees`, I get:

```
203-344-1234
202-545-8899
```

It gives the same output until `< 65` and when I compare `$4 < 66`, I get:

```
203-344-1234
654-576-4114
202-545-8899
```

I'm confused with this behaviour of `awk`. It seems like it's only comparing the first two digits of the field instead of throwing some error stating the comparison can't be done or something.

My question is: How is `awk` comparing/behaving in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't this file be a `tab` delimited file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short, this is an alphabetical comparison for GNU `awk`.

Because we compare a string (`'203-344-1234'`) with a number (`'40'`).

---

#### What is the comparison type

From [[GNU awk] String Type versus Numeric Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing):

> When two operands are compared, either string comparison or numeric
> comparison may be used. This depends upon the attributes of the
> operands, according to the following symmetric matrix:
>
> ```
>     +---------------------------------------------------------
>     |                 STRING          NUMERIC         STRNUM
>     +---------------------------------------------------------
>     | STRING  |       string          string          string
>     | NUMERIC |       string          numeric         numeric
>     | STRNUM  |       string          numeric         numeric
>     +---------------------------------------------------------
> ```

---

#### How a number is converted to string

From [[GNU awk] Comparison Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html):

> When comparing operands of mixed types, numeric operands are
> converted to strings using the value of `CONVFMT` (see section
> [Conversion of Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html)).

Following the link above, we see how the number is converted to a string for the comparison. A string is created with a call to `sprintf()` and the awk predefined variable `CONVFMT` is used for formatting, default it is `"%.6g"`, which would keep at most 6 significant digits for a decimal. But for an integer:

> As a special case, if a number is an integer, then the result of
> converting it to a string is always an integer, no matter what the value of `CONVFMT` may be.

For this case, `$4` is `203-344-1234`, is a string, not a number. And the second argument is a number, converted to the string `'40'` (regardless of the `CONVFMT` value, because it is an integer).

---

#### How to force string or number

Some additional information, from the same page:

> If, for some reason, you need to force a number to be converted to a
> string, concatenate that number with the empty string, `""`. To force a
> string to be converted to a number, add zero to that string

Sometimes, to ensure that a field will be used as numeric, we write it like `$1+0`. For example, in this case, if we force `$4+0` it will be an integer with the first three digits, `203` (that's it, the attempt to create a number ended at the first non-numeric character).

Comment: Your now-second quote is incomplete to the point of being wrong. Immediately following the text you copied, it actually links to https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html which does describe CONVFMT, but then adds "As a special case, if a number is an integer, [it is converted as an integer and CONVFMT is not used]". 40 is an integer.

Comment: Updated, thank you @dave_thompson_085